# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-route-dom' I tried alot but not able to solve

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I solved the error Module was not found but after this
**Switch did not an export error occurs.**

**I changed Switch to Routes but error Occurs**

[image]

**App.js**

```
import Chat from './Chat';
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router, Routes, Route,Switch } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (

    <Router>
      <Routes>

    <div className="App">
      
        <div className="App_body">
              {/*Sidebar*/}
              <Sidebar/>
           
              {/*Chat*/}
              <Chat/>
              
       </div>
      
    </div>
    </Routes>
    </Router>  
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Now facing this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Comment: It's the `Router`, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an `r` in the `useParams` import.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Comment: Now facing this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')
> ```

This is caused by importing and using the low-level `Router` component.

[Router](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#router)

> ```
> declare function Router(
>   props: RouterProps
> ): React.ReactElement | null;
>
> interface RouterProps {
>   basename?: string;
>   children?: React.ReactNode;
>   location: Partial<Location> | string;
>   navigationType?: NavigationType;
>   navigator: Navigator;
>   static?: boolean;
> }
> ```

It requires a `location` and `navigator` prop be passed.

Unless you have need for a custom router/etc... then the recommendation is to use the higher-level routers.

> `<Router>` is the low-level interface that is shared by all router
> components (`<BrowserRouter>`, `<HashRouter>`, `<StaticRouter>`,
> `<NativeRouter>`, and `<MemoryRouter>`). In terms of React, `<Router>` is a
> context provider that supplies routing information to the rest of the
> app.
>
> You probably never need to render a `<Router>` manually. Instead, you
> should use one of the higher-level routers depending on your
> environment. You only ever need one router in a given app.

Example:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        ... all your Route components ...
      </Routes>
    </Router>  
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not compiling because you have a typo.

You are importing useParams from 'react-route-dom' instead of 'react-route**r**-dom'.

Just change that and it should compile.

Comment: Now facing this error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'pathname')

Comment: I think there's an issue with defining your Routes config. Can you post code of it so that we can take a closer look? Here's how they did it in the documentation [link](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/route-config)